How to disable title color change when highlighted state for UIButton using UIButtonConfiguration is active?
This is how my UIButton is defined and initialized:
lazy var addButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(radius: 32, title: "+", font: .poppinsRegular.withSize(40), backgroundColor: .purple)
    button.menu = UIMenu(title: "")
    button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    return button
}()


extension UIButton {
    convenience init(
        radius: CGFloat = 0,
        title: String? = nil,
        backgroundColor: UIColor? = nil,
        foregroundColor: UIColor = .white,
        font: UIFont? = nil
    ) {
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        configuration.baseForegroundColor = foregroundColor
        configuration.title = title
        configuration.background.cornerRadius = radius
        configuration.cornerStyle = .fixed
        configuration.contentInsets = .zero
        configuration.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
            var outgoing = incoming
            outgoing.font = font
            return outgoing
        }
        configuration.baseBackgroundColor = backgroundColor
        configuration.background.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.init(configuration: configuration)
    }
}



What to change to keep my title full white even when highlighted?

UIButtonConfiguration is poorly documented thing. You need different template. May be plain instead of filled. May be this article will help: https://augmentedcode.io/2021/10/25/getting-started-with-uibutton-configuration-on-ios/

@BartłomiejSemańczyk -- as per your comment, I un-deleted my answer. Note also the Edit with what I believe is a similar but better approach.

Give this a try...
In your .titleTextAttributesTransformer:
    configuration.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
        var outgoing = incoming
        outgoing.font = font
        
        // add this line
        outgoing.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
        
        return outgoing
    }

and add a ConfigurationUpdateHandler:
let handler: UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler = { button in
    var background = UIButton.Configuration.plain().background
    background.cornerRadius = 32
    background.backgroundColor = .purple
    button.configuration?.background = background
}
    
addButton.configurationUpdateHandler = handler
    


Edit
Another (better, I think) approach...
Implement .backgroundColorTransformer in your convenience init:
extension UIButton {
    convenience init(
        radius: CGFloat = 0,
        title: String? = nil,
        backgroundColor: UIColor? = nil,
        foregroundColor: UIColor = .white,
        font: UIFont? = nil
    ) {
        // use plain instead of filled
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        configuration.baseForegroundColor = foregroundColor
        configuration.title = title
        configuration.background.cornerRadius = radius
        configuration.cornerStyle = .fixed
        configuration.contentInsets = .zero

        configuration.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
            var outgoing = incoming
            outgoing.font = font
            
            // add this line
            outgoing.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
            
            return outgoing
        }

        configuration.background.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        
        // prevent default background color/tint change
        configuration.background.backgroundColorTransformer = UIConfigurationColorTransformer { _ in
            return backgroundColor!
        }

        self.init(configuration: configuration)
    }
}

Now, we no longer need to assign a ConfigurationUpdateHandler.

I believe toy need to set image using
setBackgroundImage(_ image: UIImage?, for state: UIControl.State)
and set it both for .normal and .highlighted / .selected states so it doesn't use its default implementation
